# $http ajax AngularJS POST returns undefined index in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm sending data to an API REST service via the ajax `$http` service of AngularJS but php always says that the index is undefined. I've checked a lot of posts on SO that ask for the same error and I tried everything that they say but I still get the same error.

How I'm using the `$http` service:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: window.location.pathname+'/../../api/tasks/'+$id,
    data: {
        'title': $scope.allData.taskData[0].title,
        'content': $scope.allData.taskData[0].content,
        'usersInTask': $scope.allData.taskUsers
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
.then(function success(response){

    $scope.closeDialog();
}, function error(response){
    console.log("Error:" +response.statusText);
});
```

How I try to get values in PHP:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$users = $_POST['users'];
```

In this case, for example, it always says that `title` is an undefined index of `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read data first you need to decode it in POST format.

```
$json_input = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($json_input) {
    $_REQUEST = json_decode($json_input, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posing data it application/json format you need to read it from raw POST data. Try this:

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$title = $postData->title;
$content = $postData->content;
```

Comment: I was able to get the data like that, but trying to access to its elements it just said `"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"`